# Reading from text file and storing contents in separate arrays

Tags: java, file-io

I have a text file containing

```
r0, 0.5, 1
r1, 0.6, -1
r2, 0.2, 1
```

I want read the file and store each column in a separate array in java. This is the code I have been writing. I am only getting garbage values in the records. Also, I am not able read the float values. Please tell me how to fix this.

```
public class Model{
    private String modelname ;
private String[] records ;
private int[] targets ;
private float[] scores ;

    public Model(String name_model, String path) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {


    this.modelname = path+name_model ;
    System.out.println(this.modelname);

    BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path+name_model));
    String line=null;
    int t=0;
    while((line = bufferReader.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        //String[] strar = line.split(",");
        //String[] strar = line.split("\\s*,\\s*")  ;
        int k=1 ;
        for(String part : line.split(",")) {
            if (k==1) {
                System.out.println(part.trim());
                this.records[t] = part.trim() ;
                            }
            if (k==3)
                this.targets[t] = Integer.valueOf(part.trim()) ;
            if (k==2)
                this.scores[t] = Float.parseFloat(part.trim()) ;
            k=k+1 ;
        }
        System.out.println(this.records[t] + " " + this.targets[t] + " " + this.scores[t]);
        t=t+1;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, IOException {

    String s1, s2, s3 ;
    s1 = "./direc/" ;
    s2 = "file1.txt" ;
    s3 = s1+s2 ;
    System.out.println(s3);
    new Model(s2, s1);
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure that you code compiles? what is modelname?

Comment: if you use an ide (e.g eclipse,netbeans) it's easy to debug and follow line by line , you can put breakpoints in code, this is what you MUST learn

Comment: @user1102886 Can you actually type in the logic that you are trying to implement? that way it would be better to understand what are you trying to code?

Comment: @zerocool I am trying to read a file line by line. each line has 3 components a string a float and an integer. I want to store all the floats, integers and strings in 3 separate arrays.

Comment: What do you mean by "garbage values"?

Comment: Please, accept the most helpful answer. The question would then be treated as closed. Have a look at StackOverflow's [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the parsing. You can do away with the inner loop and avoid trimming as

```
String[] parts = line.split(", ");

this.records[t] = parts[0];
this.scores[t] = Float.parseFloat(parts[1]);
this.targets[t] = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
```

I'm assuming you forgot to put the second comma here

```
r1, 0.6, -1
```

And, since you're using a primitive `int[]` use `Integer.parseInt()` instead of `Integer.valueOf()` (which returns an `Integer` wrapper) to avoid unnecessary unboxing.

***EDIT** :*
You also need to initialize all of your Arrays like

```
private String[] records = new String[100]; // initialization is MISSING!
```

Since, in your case the size of the `Array` depends on the number of lines in your input data file it needs to be dynamic. Consider switching to an `ArrayList` that would grow dynamically.

```
private List<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<Integer> targets = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private List<Float> scores = new ArrayList<Float>();
```

Since, you need to use the wrapper types to be able to use collections; switch back to `valueOf()` methods.

```
String[] parts = line.split(", ");

this.records.add(parts[0]);
this.scores.add(Float.valueOf(parts[1]));
this.targets.add(Integer.valueOf(parts[2]));
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the error message please? It's a simple string assignment. There shouldn't be any troubles unless your input has commas missing at other places too. Please verify that.

Comment: This is the error message :                             ./dir/file1.txt
r0, 0.664534, 1
r0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Model.<init>(Model.java:106)
 at Model.main(Model.java:128)

Comment: You need to initialize your Arrays: `String[] records = new String[100];`

Comment: Thank you. I have got this fixed.

Comment: I am now closing this question. Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use braces in the `if (k==1)` case, `this.records[t]` gets assigned the last part always. The code should be:

```
        if (k==1) {
            System.out.println(part.trim());
            this.records[t] = part.trim() ;
        }
```

Also, you're missing a comma after the 0.6 on the second line of input.

Comment: forget about such detail. His code does not even compile and if you look at the sample input r0, 0.5, 1 r1, 0.6 -1 r2, 0.2, 1 how this is gonna be converted to integer(1 r1) or float? not sure about the logic as well?

Comment: The input is   r0, 0.5, 1 \n r1, 0.6, -1\n. There is a newline after each line.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way i like to use for reading files would be utilising the Scanner and File classes

so start by importing those
java.util.Scanner;
java.io.*;

then in your code (don't forget to throw IOException):
File filename = new File("filename.txt");
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(filename);

now if your using arrays, you need to know the size of the array in order to create it, and its type.

and considering your text file looks like this:
1.0 2.7 6.3 8.4 8.6
2.0 9.4 9.1 3.0 4.2
3.4 7.7 8.3 3.2 1.0

if your file can contain comma's
add this line after creating your scanner:

```
fileScanner.useDelimiter(", ")
```

and you would like 5 arrays containing each row of floats or integers etc...
create 5 arrays with the size (here 3), then use this loop to add each number:

```
int rank = 0;
double[] r1 = new double[3];
.
.
.
double[] r5 = new double[3];
while(fileScanner.hasNext())
{
    if(fileScanner.hasNextDouble()) r1[rank] = fileScanner.nextDouble();
    if(fileScanner.hasNextDouble()) r2[rank] = fileScanner.nextDouble();
    if(fileScanner.hasNextDouble()) r3[rank] = fileScanner.nextDouble();
    if(fileScanner.hasNextDouble()) r4[rank] = fileScanner.nextDouble();
    if(fileScanner.hasNextDouble()) r5[rank] = fileScanner.nextDouble();
    rank++;
}
```

Comment: The first entry of my text file has a string. The next entry is a float/ double and the third is an integer. If I use your code, then how do I read the string. Thank you very much.